# Boolean method to check array is sorted in java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, for-loop

I'm writing a method to check if an array of type double is numerically ascending in Java. However, I don't understand why I must swap where I place `return true` and `return false` for my code to work. Surely I can keep it as it is and it should still work? What am I not understanding?

```
public static boolean isSorted(double[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning at the first if statement body invokation, which means, you're checking whether first two elements are sorted. You should rather return `false`, if there is a consecutive pair, that is not sorted. If you go through the whole array and no such pair is found, then the array is sorted. This should do the job:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: representation of *if any of the element is greater than its next element, the array is not sorted*

Comment: @Andronicus If you read what the `for` loop does. It could be said, what I stated in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can quote it as if *any of the element is greater than its next element, the array is **not** sorted*, which could be represented functionally as

```
public static boolean isSorted(double[] arr) {
    return !IntStream.range(0, arr.length - 1)
            .anyMatch(i -> arr[i] > arr[i + 1]);
}
```

---

In other words, for your array to be sorted you need to ensure, *none of your elements should satisfy the condition that it is greater than the number next to in the array*.

Hence, a better functional way of writing this would be:

```
public static boolean isSorted(double[] arr) {
    return IntStream.range(0, arr.length - 1)
            .noneMatch(i -> arr[i] > arr[i + 1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I haven't yet go onto learning functional but will do so in the future